# Can anybody clarify how the resultant value is derived?

Tags: floating-point, mainframe, pl-i

Code fragment in PL/I is given below:

```
DECLARE WAVE_LTH FLOAT BINARY(21);

...

WAVE_LTH = 11001E-10B (**resultant value = 0.0244140**)
```

Can anybody clarify how the resultant value is derived?

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation (is this PL/1?) but the value seems to be 25 * 2**(-10) = 24 / 1024 = 0.02441406. 11001 in binary is 25 in decimal, the exponent is given in decimal, so -10. The trailing "B" presumably tells us that the base is binary.

Comment: Looks like PL1 (or a derivative), I think njuffa analysis is correct. Float Binary(21) declares a 21 bit accuracy binary floating point number. In this case they are using base-2 assignment

Comment: @njufa: I think you should post this as answer.

Answer (score 9):

The program statement in question is presumably from a PL/I program running on IBM System/360 hardware. This used a hexadecimal floating-point representation, for details see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture).

According to my old literature on PL/I, `FLOAT BINARY(21)` specifies a single-precision floating-point number on this platform. `21` specifies the *effective* number of mantissa bits. As this corresponds to the default value for a `FLOAT BINARY` operand, it could be left off. Due to the base-16 representation the most significant three bits of the 24-bit mantissa could be zero; this leaves a guaranteed 21 bits of precision.

The `B` suffix tells us that the floating-point literal uses base-2 representation. `11001` in binary is 25 in decimal. The exponent itself is given in decimal, so `E-10` means the scale factor is 2<sup>-10</sup>. The value of this floating-point literal constant is therefore 25 / 1024 or 0.0244140.

Comment: Good answer. I was considering voting to close as a typo (read the manual for me) but when I checked it is not so clear in the manual :-) PL/1 = PL/I.  Came as news to me a few years ago, but proved to be true. If someone is concerned today, it is now running on a z/Architechture system, no-one has used a 360 for at least 30 years. This is the latest Mainframe announcement, http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/announcement.html, and this, where Enterprise PL/I 4.2 will run is http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/hardware/z13.html

Comment: @BillWoodger Thanks for pointing out that it should be "PL/I", not "PL/1", I will fix that in my answer. I actually have never used PL/I (and used a IBM system /360 compatible machine only for a few months, a long time ago), but do have some awareness from books.

Comment: Well, that makes you answer even better :-)